# Making my browser action act as an on/off switch (with appropriate icons)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension, and I essentially want the browser action to act as an on/off switch. Whenever it is "on", it will have a certain icon and the script is executed on the page. Whenever it is "off", it has a certain icon and the script is not executed.

Here's my `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Resource Control",
    "description": "Controls what resources load from a website.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "16": "locked_16.png",
        "48": "locked_48.png",
        "128": "locked_128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "locked_16_off.png" //icon is "off" by default
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["main.js"] 
    }, 
    "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

And here's `main.js`:

```
var toggled = false;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggled = !toggled;
  if(toggled){    
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "locked_16_on.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"});
  }

  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "locked_16_off.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"alert()"});
  }

});

if (toggled) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"});
}
```

Right now I'm just working on getting this functionality working before moving on, so to test I'm just setting the page's background to red. However, whenever I load a new webpage, the icon is reverted back to the "off" icon even though the extension is still "on", and the script isn't injected into the new page. Can someone help me find where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a `tabId` to `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` it only sets the icon for when that specific tab is active. If you switch to a different tab, the icon will revert to the default.

You are only running `chrome.tabs.executeScript` when the `browserAction` is clicked on. If want code injected on every page you either need to use a content script that is injected on all tabs or listen for new tabs getting created and `executeScript` every time.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working across multiple tabs now. I also got the code injecting on every page by using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` and then executing the script within the function that's the parameter for that method. Is there any way to remove that listener when I want to switch the extension "off", though?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Thanks again for the answer! :)